# How to open Type Script Tool have installed Typescript 1.6 for VS2015

Tags: typescript

Have download and installed the Typescript 1.6 for VS2015 from this site @ http://www.typescriptlang.org/#Download  for running Type script programs do we need any other softwares. I did n't get any Visual studio icon 
could you please help me

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Typescript 1.6 for VS2015 will only be useful if you already have VS2015. To use Typescript without VS2015, install nodejs (https://nodejs.org/en/), and then install type script by `npm install -g typescript`.

Answer (score 2):

> Running Type script programs do we need any other softwares

That software only gives you typescript tools for Visual Studio. If you don't have Visual studio recommend you get setup with NodeJS + `npm install typescript -g` + some other editor (e.g. atom / atom-typescript).

Comment: For developing type script programs do we need to install any other software apart from Typescript 1.6 for VS2015. When we install Typescript 1.6 for VS2015 Visual Studio tool also come along with.  I did find any tool icon for after installing Typescript 1.6 for VS2015